# Powershell script to copy files from Sharepoint online using ClientID and refresh token to a local folder

Tags: powershell

I wanted to write a powershell script which takes all the csv files from Sharepoint Folder and copies it to a local folder. I wanted this PowerShell script to run in Azure DevOps. Appreciate your help over the same. The Powershell script should accept client ID and refresh token and copies all the csv files kept in the folder to a local folder as C:\Temp.

Appreciate your help over the same

Kind Regards,

I need a solution over the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.